# Magento 2 Hide Billing Address from Invoice email and print

Tags: magento2, invoice, billing-address, print

I get some unique case that force me to hide billing address on the invoice print and invoice email in the magento 2.

may I know, how to do that ?

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the remove **billing address** in Print invoice i think you need to override below file in your custom module.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php

And find code of

```
/* Billing Address */
    $billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($this->addressRenderer->format($order->getBillingAddress(), 'pdf'));
```

Comment: hi @Chirag Patel, thanks for your answer.. I will try it first

Comment: yes it's works, it need some modified to remove billing address, but thanks for inform core class and line code. next I will update question with my modified code.

Comment: Welcome @mrfizh :)